# junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: value but value is equal

Tags: postgresql, testing, dbunit

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
    value (table=XXX, row=XXX, col=XXX) 
expected:<2013-01-18 18:17:13.233099> 
 but was:<2013-01-18 18:17:13.233099>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)...
```

**my code:**

```
    ...
    IDataSet actualDataSet = conn.createDataSet();
    XmlDataSet expectedDataSet = new XmlDataSet(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.xml"));               

    Assertion.assertEquals(expectedDataSet, actualDataSet);
    ...
```

**conn - connection to database PostgreSql 7.1**

What is wrong?

Comment: In Postgres versions before ~8.3, date types were based on floating point types. 7.1 is terrible. You should **really** upgrade. As a workaround you coud try `where date_trunc('second', date1) = date_trunc('second', date2)`

Comment: The same on postgresql 8.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without more information, but it looks like there may be a problem with the class that represents the value in "table=XXX, row=XXX, col=XXX". What datatype is that? Some "Date"-like class? Does it correctly implement `equals()`?

A common problem with JUnit et al. is to use `assertEquals` on types where `equals()` does not compare by value - then comparison always yields `false`. This looks like one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TimestampDataType.typeCast()
```

cast to Timestamp and then other class compare objects. I don't undestend why it's doesn't work.

To avoid this problem I excluded column:

```
String[] actualTablenames = actualDataSet.getTableNames();
for (int i = 0; i < actualTableNames.length; i++) {
    ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable(actualTableNames[i]);
...
ITable filteredActualTable = DefaultColumnFilter.excludedColumnsTable(actualTable, new String[]{"changetime"});
```